# iOS SSL connection error -9824, Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, alamofire, app-transport-security

I have a pretty strange problem and I'm really not sure in which direction to go, so hopefully some of you will be able to help.

So, I'm getting the following SSL error:

> "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made, kCFStreamErrorKey = -9824".

The app is communicating with the server quite frequently (a dozen calls in a few minutes), and the strangest thing is everything is working fine (via TLS v1.2). Then every few hours, this error pops out, and after I restart the app it goes back to working normally like before. I also did an ATS diagnostics test, and it passed. Could there be an "in memory" SSL problem?

Is there a possibility to reset SSL programmatically? Thanks!

Comment: Also, the certificate isn't self signed, it's signed by CA and encryption is SHA-1

Comment: Have you read this thread: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/540

Comment: @eduardo the certificate isn't invalid, it's valid and it works 99% of the time...The 1% is bothering me.And i don't really want to disable ATS, i need it...